# Laravel validate at least one item in a form array

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I have a form with a series of numbers in an array:

```
<input type="number" name="items[{{ $sku }}]" min="0" />
<input type="number" name="items[{{ $sku }}]" min="0" />
<input type="number" name="items[{{ $sku }}]" min="0" />
```

I would like to validate that there is at least one of those input fields that has a value.

I tried the following in my **OrderCreateRequest**, yet the test is passing:

```
return [
    'items' => 'required|array|min:1'
];
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think you need a custom validation rule like the following because min is not for the elements of the array.

```
Validator::extend('check_array', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
     return count(array_filter($value, function($var) use ($parameters) { return ( $var && $var >= $parameters[0]); }));
});
```

You can create ValidatorServiceProvider and you can add these lines to boot method of ValidatorServiceProvider. Then you need to add Provider to your providers array in config/app.php.

```
App\Providers\ValidatorServiceProvider::class,
```

Or you just add them top of the action of your controller.

At the end you can use it like this in your validation rules.

```
'items' => 'check_array:1',
```

Note: if I understand you correctly it works.

Comment: Great solution! Thank you.

Comment: dont forget to add `'check_array' => 'at least one item is required',` to `langs/*/validation.php`

Comment: for some reason this now always return `0` check http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7781961e4dd2aee88a4e873d52c8f2a4c994932b

Comment: Your code has some logical errors. so you should try like this http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d0447c13a3a166373dd0ff18b300f7bb5b7272b8

Comment: The string value of a date 01/08/2021 fails the validator (php 7.4.8) since the parameter is a string and the slash breaks the behavior, I would use `!empty($var)` instead

Answer (score 11):

In addition ot Hakan SONMEZ's answer, to check if at least one array element is set, the [Rule](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#using-rule-objects) object can be used. For example create rule class and name it ArrayAtLeastOneRequired().

To create new rule class run console command:

```html
php artisan make:rule ArrayAtLeastOneRequired
```

Then in created class edit method passes():

```html
public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        foreach ($value as $arrayElement) {
            if (null !== $arrayElement) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Use this rule to check if at least one element of array is not null:

```html
Validator::make($request->all(), [
  'array' => [new ArrayAtLeastOneRequired()],
 ]);
```

Comment: Great answer! Please note the validation rule should be applied to the array `'array'` and not to the array element `'array.*'`  otherwise the foreach loop won't be able to iterate .

Comment: This is precisely what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

If you are using this in your controller file then I guess it should be

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'items' => 'required|min:1'
]);
```

or this one

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    "items.*" => 'required|min:1',
]);
```

you can refer [How to validate array in Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42258185/how-to-validate-array-in-laravel]) to this as well.

Comment: second example with `items.*` will check that all values in items array should have at-least 1 character in it, but here we have to validate to minimum 1 element should be there in array so, first example is right but second one is wrong because it will check values.

Comment: First example is wrong as well because it would pass an array with a single null value. This answer doesn't address the question and shouldn't be upvoted.

Comment: Not correct . i tried it

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer is ok, and it is working fine, but if you don't want to create function and other stuff then the another workaround which i have used is

that you can directly state the element of array as `items.0` and make that input required, it will not care about other inputs but it will make first input required, it is not usable in all the cases but in my case it is useful.

in your `OrderCreateRequest`:

```
public function rules()
{
   return [
       "items.0" => "required",
   ];
}
```

And if your items are not dynamic and not in very large amount then you can use `required_without_all` as below:

```
public function rules()
{
   return [
       "items.0" => "required_without_all:items.1,items.2",
       "items.1" => "required_without_all:items.0,items.2",
       "items.2" => "required_without_all:items.0,items.1",
   ];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

"size" rule is used to match exact no. of items in array (if incoming parameter is an array) and same goes for "min" rule i.e it count minimum no. of elements in an array (if incoming parameter is an array)

```
$this->validate($request, ['my_array' => 'size:6']); // array must have 6 items

$this->validate($request, ['my_array' => 'min:1']); // there must be 1 item in array
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-size

Answer (score -2):

```
'items'   => 'required|array', // validate that field must be from array type and at least has one value
'items.*' => 'integer' // validate that every element in that array must be from integer type
```

and you can add any other validation rules for those elements like: `'items.*' => 'integer|min:0|max:100'`

Comment: the `min` attribute has nothing to do with the count items, instead it checks the value itself

Comment: @behz4d and that what i meant to check the elements. 
`*` here it means apply the rules on every element in this array.
not checking the count

Answer (score -3):

You can set your rules for array and foreach elements.

```
public function rulez(Request $req) {
        $v = Validator::make($req->all(), [
            'items'   => 'required|array|min:1',
            'items.*' => 'required|integer|between:0,10'

        ]);

        if ($v->fails())
            return $v->errors()->all();
}
```

First rule say that items must be an array with 1 element at least.
Second rule say that each elements of items must be an integer between 0 and 10.

If the rules seem not to work, try to dump your $req->all().

```
dump($req->all());
```

Comment: that means all elements of input array are required and they can be minimum 1. He wants a validation rule which makes at least one element of array is required  and others are optional.

Comment: ok, you can use `'items' => 'required|array|min:1'`
Are you sure to receive the Request parameters correctly?

Comment: Please add a short explanation.

Comment: I am not the one asked the question.

Answer (score -3):

```
$valid = Validator($request->all(), [
    'type' => 'required|string|in:city,region,country',
]);

if ($valid->fails()) return response()->json($valid->errors(), 400);
```

Comment: a verbal explanation is often helpful

Comment: This answer is incorrect and doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Incorrect answer.