# Validate array of inputs in form in Laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-validation, laravel-5.7

My form has the same input field multiple times. My form field is as follows:

```
<input type='text' name='items[]'>
<input type='text' name='items[]'>
<input type='text' name='items[]'>
```

And request contains ($request['items'):

```
array:1 [▼
  "items" => array:3 [▼
    0 => "item one"
    1 => "item two"
    2 => "item three"
  ]
]
```

I want atleast one of the items to be filled. My current validation in the controller is

```
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),[
        'items.*' => 'required|array|size:1'
    ]);
```

It does not work. I tried with combination of size, required, nullable. Nothing works.

Comment: you want this fill in your database ? and check all requirements right ?

Comment: Yes. The above code is in my controller.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45758449/laravel-validate-at-least-one-item-in-a-form-array

Comment: Try without `.*` and change size to min as `'items' => 'required|array|min:1'`

Comment: I tried the solution, did not work

Comment: why don't you post your controller code too

Answer (score 7):

In fact, it's enough to use:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(),[
        'items' => 'required|array'
    ]);
```

The changes made:

- use `items` instead of `items.*` - you want to set rule of general items, if you use `items.*` it means you apply rule to each sent element of array separately
- removed `size:1` because it would mean you want to have exactly one element sent (and you want at least one). You don't need it at all because you have `required` rule. You can read [documentation for required rule](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#rule-required) and you can read in there that empty array would case that `required` rule will fail, so this `required` rule for array makes that array should have at least 1 element, so you don't need `min:1` or `size:1` at all

Answer (score 3):

You can check it like this:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    "items"    => "required|array|min:1",
    "items.*"  => "required|string|distinct|min:1",
]);
```

In the example above:

- "items" must be an array with at least 1 elements.
- Values in the "items" array must be distinct (unique) strings, at least 1 characters long.

Comment: In this case, $validator->fails() returns true even when a field is not empty

Comment: Are you entering the distinct field value?

Comment: "items" => array:4 [▼
    0 => null
    1 => null
    2 => "item-three"
    3 => null
  ] 
This is my input

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom rule with a closure.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#custom-validation-rules

To check if an array has all null values check it with array_filter which returns false if they're all null.

So something like...

```
  $request->validate([

    'items' => [
      // $attribute = 'items', $value = items array, $fail = error message as string
       function($attribute, $value, $fail) {
         if (!array_filter($value)) {
           $fail($attribute.' is empty.');
         } 
       },
     ]
   ]);
```

This will set the error message: 'items is empty."

Answer (score 1):

Knowing you are using the latest version of Laravel, I really suggest looking into [Form Request feature](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#form-request-validation). That way you can decouple validation from your controller keeping it much cleaner.

Anyways as the answer above me suggested, it should be sufficient for you to go with:

```
'items' => 'required|array'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Do it normally as you always do:

```
 $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),[
    'items' => 'required'
  ]);
```

Comment: Does not work as well. $validator->fails() returns false all the time for that condition

Comment: You mean $validator->fails() always returns false even if you pass an item in items

Comment: It's working fine in my project, there might be some thing wrong in your code, But I have laravel 5.6 in my project but you have 5.7 that might be the problem or something else.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
$validator = $request->validate([
    "items"    => "required|array|min:3",
    "items.*"  => "required|string|distinct|min:3",
]);
```