# Laravel array validation in 5.5 version

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

**Validation code**

```
'event' => 'required|array',
'event.*.start_date_time' => 'required|date_format:Y-m-d|after:today',
'event.*.end_date_time' => 'required|date_format:Y-m-d|after:today',
'event.*.description' => 'required|spam_free',
```

**Error message code**

```
if ($messages->has('event')) {
    $fieldId = 'event';
    $errors [] = getErrorMessage($fieldId, $messages->first($fieldId));
}
if ($messages->has('event.*.start_date_time')) {
    $fieldId = 'event.*.start_date_time';
    $errors [] = getErrorMessage($fieldId, $messages->first($fieldId));
}
if ($messages->has('event.*.end_date_time')) {
    $fieldId = 'event.*.end_date_time';
    $errors [] = getErrorMessage($fieldId, $messages->first($fieldId));
}
if ($messages->has('event.*.description')) {
    $fieldId = 'event.*.description';
    $errors [] = getErrorMessage($fieldId, $messages->first($fieldId));
}
```

**Error message**

```
{
   "fieldld": "event.*.start_date_time",
   "message": "The event.0.start_date_time field is required."
},
{
    "fieldld": "event.*.end_date_time",
    "message": "The event.0.end_date_time field is required."
},
{
    "fieldld": "event.*.description",
    "message": "The event.0.description field is required."
},
```

**Array**

```
event[0].start_date_time:2017-03-22 15:42:22
event[0].end_date_time:2017-03-22 15:42:22
event[0].description:test description
```

Can anyone help my why its not validation array and why i am not getting proper error message.

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: Please try hasOne insted of has

Comment: @AshishDetroja my main concern is validating array. error message i can customize.

Comment: please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42258185/how-to-validate-array-in-laravel maybe helping you.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys i was passing array in wrong format.

```
event[0][start_date_time]:2017-12-12
event[0][end_date_time]:2017-12-12
event[0][description]:asfdsfdsf
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Validator for array.

```
 $validate = Validator::make($data,[
            'start_time' => 'required|after:today',
        ]);

if($validate->fails()){

 return $validate->getMessageBag()->toArray();

}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#validating-arrays