# Can't validate input file in laravel

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-5, vue.js, httprequest

I want to validate a `file input` but the validation does not work it always return `The given data was invalid.` even if the file given meets the validation requirements knowing that I'm uploading **multiple** files at once:

Here's the **validation** I use :

```
    Validator::make($request->all('files'), [
        'files' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048'
    ])->validate();
```

And here's the **HTML** I use :

```
<input type="file" id="files" ref="files" multiple v-on:change="uoloadFiles()" name="files"/>
```

Knowing that I use **vue** to handle the form submission.

Thanks for helping

Comment: I think this is since you are uploading multiple files at once, which makes `files` an array, not a single file. Not enough information given in the question to verify that.

Comment: Yes I'm uploading multiple files

Comment: You will need something like [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#validating-arrays)

Comment: That's what I'm using

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work since you are uploading multiple files, each file should be validated separately.

```
Validator::make($request->all('files'), [
    'files.*' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048'
])->validate();
```

Note the `*`.

Further reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42258185/how-to-validate-array-in-laravel)

Answer (score 0):

if you have only this field you can do:

```
Validator::make($request->only('files'), [
    'files.*' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048'
])->validate();
```

otherwise use `all` method without arguments:

```
 Validator::make($request->all(), [
      'files.*' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048'
 ])->validate();
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$this->validate(request(), [
         'files' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048'
    ]);
```

i dont think you need `image` just `mimes` is fine