# laravel 5 : how to validate multi dimensional checkbox

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Hello i have the following in my view

```
<table class="table">
   <tbody>
       @foreach($products as $indexKey => $product)
       <tr>
          <td>
             <input type="checkbox name="order_products[{{$indexKey}}][id]" value="{{$product->id}}"/>
           </td>
           <td>
             <input type="text" name="order_products[{{$indexKey}}][quantity]" value=""/>
          </td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
   </tbody>
</table>
```

and in my controller

```
$this->validate($request,[
    'order_products'=>'required'
])
```

how can I validate that if one checkbox is checked, make sure the 'quantity' is not empty?

i checked so many websites and nothing comes close to my answer, they are all using just one dimensional array.

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this if it works

```
$this->validate($request,[
    'order_products'=>'required|array',
    'order_products.id' => 'required',
    'order_products.quantity' => 'required'
])
```

Comment: thank you @wellwisher but doesn't seems to work, i get error back even after all checkbox are clicked

Comment: "the order products.product id is required, the order products.quantity is required"

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42258185/how-to-validate-array-in-laravel)