# Validation of array in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation

I am building a small application in `Laravel 5.6` where I am having an api which takes an array in format `[1,2,5,90,25]` I want to validate as required field in my validation rule.

I tried creating a request and validating the same as:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'ProjectType.*'=>  'required',
    ]
}

public function messages()
{
    return [
        'projectType.*.required' => 'Project type is required',
    ];
}
```

But this thing is not working out, even if an empty array `[]` is being passed it accepts it.

How can we achieve these kind of array format

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/42258677/2305600

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to validate array in Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42258185/how-to-validate-array-in-laravel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must validate at the top level of the array, you may want this validation:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'ProjectType'=>  'required|array',
        'ProjectType.*'=>  'required',
    ]
}

public function messages()
{
    return [
        'projectType.*.required' => 'Project type is required',
    ];
}
```