# Validator request array

Tags: arrays, json, laravel, validation, laravel-5.5

In this problem , i must add validator to request array

example form :
[image]

and result request https://pastebin.com/xhfnxRdy

i have use `required='required'` but thats not the only solution . i must use validator .

i have read https://stackoverflow.com/a/42258677/10139778 but not working on me .

Comment: Please add some code, show us what you have tried and what you expect to happen and what currently happens. Saying you must use laravel's validation package isn't really a question. If you have to use it, use it? Or look at making [custom requests](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#creating-form-requests).

Comment: Question needs more detail. General info on validating arrays in Laravel form requests here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#validating-arrays