# Validate JS Array request in Laravel Controller

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, validation, controller

I just want to ensure that my data, coming from a JS side, is an array. So from  [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42258185/how-to-validate-array-in-laravel) it is visible that writing `'array'` in the validation would be enough. But in my case, when I write:

```
$request->validate([
    'tags' => 'array',
]);
```

and pass an array `[1,2,3]` using [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/), I get an error `["The tags must be an array."]`, and php handles it as a string, so when I try to get, for example, the first element `$request->tags[0]`, I receive `'['`. What's wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears as though when you pass `[1,2,3]`, it's not an array, it's literally just a string.  When you treat a string like an array in PHP, it will give you that character so `$request->tags[0]` is just giving you the first character in the string which is `[`.

When using postman and adding your key value pairs, set the keys and values like so...

```
+--------+-------+
| Key    | Value |
+--------+-------+
| tags[] | 1     |
| tags[] | 2     |
| tags[] | 3     |
+--------+-------+
```

Comment: Is it a Postman-specific issue, or I have to do similar stuff in real JS also?

Comment: I wouldn't call it a Postman issue.  It's just how PHP expects the query strings to be formatted when using arrays.  ex `test.php?tags=[1,2,3]` PHP would determine tags to be a string.  `test.php?tags[]=1&tags[]=2&tags[]=3` PHP would determine to be an array.  If you are using JS, depending on how you do it, there's a good chance that will be handled for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form ..>
  <input name="tags[]" value="1">
  <input name="tags[]" value="2">
  <input name="tags[]" value="2">
</form>

<script>
 //your code to serialise and post form through JS goes here
</script>
```

In your request class

```
//TagsRequest.php
public function rules(){
  return [
    'tags'=>['array'],
    'tags.*'=>[
       //add rules for tags array elements
    ]
  ]

}
```