# Laravel array validation dont show error message

Tags: php, arrays, string, laravel, validation

Firstly I can say that after search I dont find any solution about this. I do validation array like this post: [laravel validation array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42258185/how-to-validate-array-in-laravel])

I need validate each size array position. I write this validation code:

```
   // Fields validation
    $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required|max:150',
        'theySay' => 'nullable|array',
        'theySay.*' => 'string|max:1000',
        'theyDontSay' => 'nullable|array',
        'theyDontSay.*' => 'string|max:1000',
    ]
```

Where theySay and theyDontSay are both array of strings. In migration I have both fields (text) like strings of 1000 characters.

```
        $table->string('text', 1000);
```

And validation works correctly. I mean, if put a text greater than 1000 chars I cannot save but..dont show any error message.

I want the error message to be shown in the input just like the rest of the fields.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

[image]

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

```
'YOUR_FIELD' => '...|...|max:1000| ...'
```

Look at the Laravel validation [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/validation) for more information

Comment: If you see my question, my code strictly follows the laravel validation rules written in the documentation. You can see it here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#validating-arrays.

My question is not that

Comment: Problem is in vaidation response. The error is not shown

Comment: Do you have error block in your view code?Do you compose it?

Comment: Any error in console is showed. If I enter a string <1000 I dont have any problem (validation works). But if I enter a string > 1000 validation works and I cannot save the element. But error dont appear. I update my question

Comment: do you have below code in your view file?
`
@foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
   {!! $errors->first() !!}
@endforeach

`

Comment: If I put these code result is the same. Any error is showed

Answer (score -2):

Please put below code in your blade file for show any error message.

```
@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

Comment: This does not answer the question