# How to validate array field value in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-validation

I have created the form and created multiple fields.

```
<input name="members[]" type="text" class="form-control">
<input name="members[]" type="text" class="form-control">
<input name="members[]" type="text" class="form-control">
```

set the validation from the Form Request for the input fields

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'password' => 'required|max:30',
        'members.*' => 'required|max:12',
    ];
}
```

How can we check the members' field value exists in the database using the validation?
For password using like this

```
'password' => ['required', function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
    if (!\Hash::check($value, $this->user()->password)) {
        $fail('Old Password did not match to our records.');
    }
}],
```

Comment: What is the value of the input and what does it map to in your database?

Comment: yes it maps with the database and field name  is member

Comment: That is not what I asked, is it an integer, is it a piece of text. What is the value and which table and column does is map to?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to validate array in Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42258185/how-to-validate-array-in-laravel)

Comment: @DhavalNaphade I want to check field value from database and want to set the query example its autocomplete field with phone number and want to check phone number exist in database or not

Comment: @DhavalNaphade yes its was useful for me thank you

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the `exists` validation rule.

Just extend your existing validation rules for members:

```
'members.*' => 'required|max:12|exists:{phone number table},{phone nummber column}',
```