# How to validate an array of datetimes in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, validation, eloquent, laravel-8

I have a form that submits an array named `prazos`, and I want to make sure each item is a valid datetime or null. Following [the answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42258185/how-to-validate-array-in-laravel) and the [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation), I have this in my Controller:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

// ...

$rules = array([
            'prazos' => 'required|array',
            'prazos.*' => 'nullable|date'
           ]);

$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
$data = $validator->valid()['prazos'];
foreach($data as $id => $prazo) {
    // use $data to update my database
    // ...
}
```

The issue is, the validator is not actually stopping invalid content. If I try to submit "loldasxyz" or other gibberish, I get an error from the database. What am I doing wrong?

Note: previously I had been using validators with the syntax `$data = $request->validate($rules)`, but for some reason it didn't work for the array-type data (`$data` came back empty). I'm not sure if there is some difference in how those different methods work.

Edit: this is what the parameter bag in `$request` looks like when I test it (the indices are ids, which is why they start at 1):

```
    #parameters: array:3 [▼
      "_token" => "Rf6mAp4lqhpZzQRxaxYsees1M0NfrFKpbGe4Hy28"
      "_method" => "PUT"
      "prazos" => array:5 [▼
        1 => "2021-03-22 21:21"
        2 => "2021-03-03 11:27"
        3 => "jhbkjhg"
        4 => null
        5 => "2021-03-02 14:21"
      ]
    ]
```

And this is what the validated `$data` comes out as:

```
array:5 [▼
  1 => "2021-03-22 21:21"
  2 => "2021-03-03 11:27"
  3 => "jhbkjhg"
  4 => null
  5 => "2021-03-02 14:21"
]
```

I wish it would tell me the third value is invalid.

Comment: dd your request and see if its coming as `prazos[0], prazos[1] `or your input are coming in some other format, and I think you should `nullable` instead of `sometimes`

Comment: you're right, since there are no missing values, just null ones... done.

Answer (score 0):

Heres what youre looking for:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-date-equals

The field under validation must be equal to the given date. The dates will be passed into the PHP strtotime function in order to be converted into a valid DateTime instance.

Comment: This looks like it will only validate a specific date. I want any valid date.