# How to Validate an array in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-validation

I am trying to apply the suggestions provided in this question [How to validate array in Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42258185/how-to-validate-array-in-laravel)

So my validation is

```php
'topics' => 'required|array'
```

> Topics are required

This works well especially if topics is an array greater than 1

unfortunately is I pass `[]` an empty array the validation fails

How can I validate that the input is an array, Its not null and empty array is allowed?

Below attempt fails

```php
 'topics' => 'required|array|min:0',
```

> Topics are required

Below works, the problem is that even null values are permitted

```
 'topics' => 'array',
```

Comment: What's about `'topics' => 'nullable|array'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use [present](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-present) validation

The field under validation must be present in the input data but can be empty.

```
 'topics' => 'present|array'
```

Comment: Note, that unless you use the `ConvertEmptyStringsToNull` middleware, an empty string can still pass the validation: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/18948

Comment: thanks @naszy, I did not know that before

Answer (score 4):

Validating array based form input fields doesn't have to be a pain. You may use "dot notation" to validate attributes within an array. For example, if the incoming HTTP request contains a `photos[profile]` field, you may validate it like so:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'photos.profile' => 'required|image',
]);
```

You may also validate each element of an array. For example, to validate that each email in a given array input field is unique, you may do the following:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'person.*.email' => 'email|unique:users',
    'person.*.first_name' => 'required_with:person.*.last_name',
]);
```

In your case, if you want to validate that the elements inside your array are not empty, the following would suffice:

```
'topics' => 'required|array',
'topics.*' => 'sometimes|integer', // <- for example.
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, What I have picked from your answer is how to validate each individual element but my problem is not the individual elements. The issue is that `null` is validated as okay but if I add `required` not validation fails even for empty array

Comment: In simple terms, I would like a way to validate that the request is not null and the request is either an empty array or an array with values

Comment: In the examples with photos, there is the solution, however I have updated the answer in your particular case.