# Laravel validate array values contained in list

Tags: laravel

I am passing an array in a request to my api. Each value within the array must be within a pre-defined list.

If my list is: `name,description,title`

```
name, title //valid
different, title //invalid
```

I tried `array|in:name,description,title` but I think for that I can only pass a string.

Can I do this without using a custom rule?

Comment: Does this question help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42258185/how-to-validate-array-in-laravel

Comment: What do you mean when you say "..I think for that I can only pass a string"? Does that mean your array does not contain strings?

Comment: I think your link did help `'values.*' => 'string|in:name,title,description'` seems to work

Comment: glad to hear it helped. Perhaps add your own answer and accept it so your question does not show up as unanswered :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Validate each string in the array:

```
'values.*' => 'string|in:name,title,description'
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at ["Validating Nested Array Input"](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#validating-nested-array-input)

If I understand you correctly your validation rules should be (untested)

```php
[
   '*.name' => 'required|string',
   '*.description' => 'required|string',
]
```

Maybe you also want to [exclude unvalidated Keys](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#excluding-unvalidated-array-keys)