# Livewire binding model radio button error

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

i'm trying to build a polls system using livewire but i got some errors

here is my blade

```html
@foreach ($questions as $index => $question)
    <div class="row">
        <div class="box-header with-border">
            <i class="fa fa-question-circle text-black fs-20 me-10"></i>
            <h4 class="box-title">{{ $question->title }}</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="box-body">
            <div class="demo-radio-button">
                @foreach ($answers as $key => $answer)
                    <input wire:model="question{{ $question->id }}" type="radio"
                        id="answer{{ $question->id }}{{ $key }}"
                        class="radio-col-primary" value="{{ $key }}">
                    <label
                        for="answer{{ $question->id }}{{ $key }}">{{ $answer }}</label>
                @endforeach
                @error('question')
                    <div class="text-danger text-bold">{{$message}}</div>
                @enderror
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

my Livewire class

```php
public $question = [];

public function render() {
    $category = PollCategory::findOrFail($this->category->id);
    $subCategories = PollSubCategory::where('poll_category_id', $category->id)->get();
    $answers = PollAnswer::all();
    return view('livewire.polls', compact('category', 'subCategories', 'answers'));
}
```

The Error is

> Property [$question41] not found on component: [polls]

Any help please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you did it wrong way,

solution:

```
<input wire:model="question.{{ $question->id }}"
```

$question{{ $question->id }} equal $question41

$question.{{ $question->id }} equal to $question[41]

that's why u receive error `Property [$question41] not found on component`

Comment: i tried it but validation not working to all questions
it's validate one question only

$this->validate([
            'question.*' => 'required',

        ]);

Comment: 'Asterisk symbol (*) is used to check values in the array, not the array itself.' [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42258185/how-to-validate-array-in-laravel](array validation asterik)

Comment: i want to make all questions are required

how can i do this ?

Comment: The only solution come out from my mind right now is

Did your question array comes in key pair? If so
```
foreach($question as $key => $q) {
    $this->validate([
         'question.'.$key => ['required']
     ]);
}
```

Comment: question array comes in $question->id not $key pair .. so i need to foreach my array question ?

Comment: Its not working anymore if you use Livewire 3 since they unsupport nested binding except you have to activate it from config