# How to validate array in Request rules laravel?

Tags: laravel

I create request in laravel for validation where i have to validate phone number array.How to validate it. Below i am sharing:

```
Array that i pass in postman is:
    {
        "name": "test nbame",
        "phone_number": {
            "number": "+8896 5432",
            "internationalNumber": "+852 7896 5432",
            "nationalNumber": "+8896 5432",
            "e164Number": "+85278965432",
            "countryCode": "HK",
            "dialCode": "+852"
        },
        "designation": "xyz"
    }
   
public function rules()
        {
            return [
                'name'           => 'required',
                'dial_number'    =>  'required',
                'phone_number'   => 'required|regex:/(^[0-9 ]+$)+/',
                //'image'           =>  'required',
            ];
        }
```

how to validate phone_number array.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to validate array in Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42258185/how-to-validate-array-in-laravel)

Answer (score 1):

Based on your `json` you can do something like below

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name'           => 'required',
        'dial_number'    =>  'required',
        'phone_number'   => 'required|array',
        'phone_number.number' => 'required|regex:/(^[0-9 ]+$)+/',
        'phone_number.internationalNumber' => 'required|regex:/(^[0-9 ]+$)+/',
        'phone_number.nationalNumber' => 'required|regex:/(^[0-9 ]+$)+/',
        'phone_number.e164Number' => 'required',
        'phone_number.countryCode' => 'required|string',
        'phone_number.countryCode' => 'required|string',
        'phone_number.dialCode' => 'required',
        //'image'           =>  'required',
    ];
}
```

for more info you can visit [laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#validating-arrays)

Answer (score 0):

You're validating against a nested array in Laravel:

```php
public function rules()
        {
            return [
                ...
                'phone_number.number'   => 'required|regex:/(^[0-9 ]+$)+/',
            ];
        }
```

Read more in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#validating-nested-array-input).

Comment: no t working this one. in postman i pass phone number array how to validate national number and dialcode

Comment: Refer to the docs I posted. You should find your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You will check the number by regex. You will find a lot of variants of possible phone numbers. That means that you need a regex which is very flexible. How flexible the regex should be depends on you. here is an example:

`'phone_number.number'   => 'required|regex:/(^[0-9 ]+$)+/',`