# Laravel not validating array input

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to validate some input array fields in Laravel.  My application reports back the field is required, even though it has been filled out.

The validation code I have is:

```
$this->validate($request, [
        'first_name'        => 'required',
        'last_name'         => 'required',
        'telephone'         => 'required',
        'email'             => 'unique:contacts,email,' . $request->id,
        'address'           => 'required',
        'address.0.address_line_1'         => 'required',
    ]);
```

The full posted array is:

```
Array
(
[id] => 1
[_token] => xxx
[first_name] => Joe
[last_name] => Bloggs
[contact_name] => Joe Bloggs
[telephone] => 077
[email] => joe@test.com
[address] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                ['address_line_1'] => sss
                ['address_line_2'] => 
                ['city'] => 
                ['county'] => 
                ['postcode'] => 
                ['property_type'] => site
            )

    )

)
```

My input fields are constructed like so:

```
address[0]['address_line_1']
```

I'm getting the validation message error:

```
The address.0.address line 1 field is required.
```

Anyone know what's wrong here?

Comment: duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42258185/how-to-validate-array-in-laravel

Comment: It's not a duplicate - i've tried what they said in the same thread, but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: What if you remove your requirement of `address`? It might conflict.

Comment: You mean change the name

Answer (score 0):

That's because you don't have any `address_line_1` or `address_line_2` in your array validation but you have posted those two elements.

You only have `address.0.address_line_1` and there's no `address.0.address_line_1` inside your posted data.

The elements of your array validation should be the same with what you posted.
In your case, you can remove `address.0.address_line_1` and add 2 more elements of your array validation.

```
'address_line_1' => 'required',
'address_line_2' => 'required',
```

The updated answer :

```
'address' => 'required|array',
'address.*' => 'required|array',
'address.*.address_line_1' => 'required|string',
```

Comment: But my form fields look like: address[0]['address_line_1']

Comment: Try to change `'address.0.address_line_1'` with `'address.*.address_line_1'`

Comment: Please change the description of your posted array to posted address array because I thought that it was your full posted array.

Comment: tried this already, but get the same...

Comment: I've just posted the full array which is returned

Comment: what the error message when you try with that : 'address_line_1' => 'required', ? And maybe try like this :        'address.address_line_1'         => 'required',

Comment: @V4n1ll4 try to remove `'address.0.address_line_1'         => 'required',` and add more elements like my updated answer

Comment: Still getting the same...

Comment: Try again my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your validator with this

```
$this->validate($request, [
   'first_name' => 'required',
   'last_name'  => 'required',
   'telephone'  => 'required',
   'email' => 'unique:contacts,email,' . $request->id,
   'address' => 'required',
    'address.*' => 'required',
    'address.*.address_line_1' => 'required',
]);
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's still failing validation saying "The address.0.address_line_1 field is required." even though it's filled.

Comment: I'm thinking this could possibly b a bug with Laravel version 5.2.45

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure out what was causing the issue...it was actually to do with the form input field names.

I removed the single quotes from the input names and it worked!

I changed:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="address[0]['address_line_1']">
```

To, this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="address[0][address_line_1]">
```

And it worked!  Hope it helps someone else.