# Storing array and only accepting arrays that have a value in them in Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

How do I store arrays in laravel, for example, my database table only has firstname, middlename, and lastname in the column. and i have a field for for different family members in my form which shares the same column, so im planning to store the data as an array, the problem is, i cant store it. what is the problem in my code.

**Ajax jquery code.** I can get data in my ajax, but when it comes to the controller, it says undefined

```js
$("#btn-save").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = [
        {
            firstname: $('#father_firstName').val(),
            middlename: $('#father_middleName').val(),
            lastname: $('#father_lastName').val(),
        },
        {
            firstname: $('#mother_firstName').val(),
            middlename: $('#mother_middleName').val(),
            lastname: $('#mother_lastName').val(),
        },
    ];
```

**Controller.php code**

```php
public function familyRegister(Request $request)
{
    // Initialize variables
    $data['user1'] = UserInfoModel::where('app_id',  '=', Session::get('loginId'))->first();
    $data['user2'] = FamilyMembersModel::where('seq_id', '=', Session::get('loginId'))->first();

    // Validate input
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), []);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json([
            'status' => 400,
            'errors' => $validator->messages(),
        ]);
    } else {
        $familyMembers = [];
        if ($request->input('father_firstName')) {
            $familyMembers[] = [
                'firstname' => $request->input('father_firstName'),
                'middlename' => $request->input('father_middleName'),
                'lastname' => $request->input('father_lastName'),   
            ];
        }
        if ($request->input('mother_firstName')) {
            $familyMembers[] = [
                'firstname' => $request->input('mother_firstName'),
                'middlename' => $request->input('mother_middleName'),
                'lastname' => $request->input('mother_lastName'),
            ];
        }
         
        foreach ($familyMembers as $member) {
            $record = new FamilyMembersModel;
            $record->firstname = $member['firstname'];
            $record->middlename = $member['middlename'];
            $record->lastname = $member['lastname'];
            $record->save();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what does the result if you use `dd($request->all())` ?

Comment: **array:1 [ // app\Http\Controllers\CustomAuthController.php:1942
  "undefined" => null
]** or did i just dd at the wrong place?

Comment: @CaptainCRAZY the issue is on the JS side, you are sending "undefined" string to the server, not your data

Comment: What should i do or change @DmitryK.?

Comment: @CaptainCRAZY what's your question? Did you see answer to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending an array of objects. You can validate data like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58323845/12503693

Then you can access request data like this:

```
$data = $request->input();

$father_firstName = $data[0]['father_firstName'];
$father_middleName = $data[0]['father_middleName'];
$father_lastName= $data[0]['father_lastName'];

$mother_firstName = $data[1]['mother_firstName'];
$mother_middleName = $data[1]['mother_middleName'];
$mother_lastName= $data[1]['mother_lastName'];
```

OR

```
$father_firstName = $request->input('0.father_firstName');
$father_middleName = $request->input('0.father_middleName');
$father_lastName = $request->input('0.father_lastName');

$mother_firstName = $request->input('1.mother_firstName');
$mother_middleName = $request->input('1.mother_middleName');
$mother_lastName = $request->input('1.mother_lastName');
```

Comment: Thanks, i'll read the documentation first

Comment: Sorry, i gave wrong link. Now it is correct link.